# Suppose that $x_n \to x$ in norm as $n \to \infty$. Does it follow that $\|x_n\| \to \|x\|$ as $n \to \infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

H is an infinite dimensional Hilbert space with associated norm $\|\cdot\|$, and $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence in $H$. $x\in H$.

Comment: Also, please use MathJax. You can start to familiarize yourself with the tool by taking a look at my edit of your post. Then there is a tutorial somewhere here in MathStackExchange

Comment: HINT: Use [Reverse triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proposed claim is true. Indeed, one has
\begin{align*}
\|x\| = \|x - x_{n} + x_{n}\| \leq \|x - x_{n}\| + \|x_{n}\|
\end{align*}

Similarly, the following relation holds
\begin{align*}
\|x_{n}\| = \|x - x_{n} + x\| \leq \|x - x_{n}\| + \|x\|
\end{align*}

Gathering both results, one has that
\begin{align*}
|\|x\| - \|x_{n}\|| \leq \|x - x_{n}\|
\end{align*}

Since we know that $x_{n}\to x$, let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then there exists $n_{\varepsilon} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
\begin{align*}
n\geq n_{\varepsilon}\Rightarrow |\|x\| - \|x_{n}\|| \leq \|x - x_{n}\| \leq \varepsilon
\end{align*}
whence we conclude that $\|x_{n}\|$ converges to $\|x\|$.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Do you mean <\epsilon??

Comment: It is usual to make use of $\epsilon$, but I prefer $\varepsilon$.

Comment: I didn't refer to the epsilon, but the equality. You wrote smaller or equal to, but isn't it just smaller than?

Comment: Both ways are correct.